# Strange battery behavior: how to diagnose power supply monitor?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, power-management, acpi, battery

I have a problem that I can not determine with the battery of my computer. In case it was of use, I use *Arch Linux* with `dwm`, although I don't think it's relevant to the case.

I get the battery with `acpi`:

```
$ acpi
Battery 0: Charging, 93%, 00:06:21 until charged
Battery 1: Discharging, 0%, rate information unavailable
```

First of all, I don't understand where `Battery 1` comes from. In `/sys/class/power_supply/` there is `AC0`, `BAT0` and `hidpp_battery_0`. I can get the battery without problems in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`, and I get logically the same value as in `acpi`.

```
$ ls /sys/class/power_supply/
AC0  BAT0  hidpp_battery_0
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity
93
```

This value is obtained from the percentage calculation of the values of `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW` (`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now`) on `POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL` (`/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full`); for example 100*675000/900000=75% in `capacity`.

**About the strange battery life:**

The problem is that the battery wears out very quickly on some occasions, lasting less than half an hour even. I might think that there is something wrong with the hardware or the battery itself.

However, there are some things that make me doubt and that I don't quite understand:

1. As I said, there are times when the battery lasts very little.
2. But despite lasting a short time, it stays at 8% for a long time. Always starting from 8, that is, 8, 7, 6, 5... Being at this threshold as much or more than in the rest of the percentages.

In the following image it is observed in detail, how the battery goes down at the same speed at which it is charged, however it remains stable at the threshold of the 8 for quite a long time. For clarity I have colored the charge times yellow-orange:

[image: perc graph]

3. Sometimes, I turn off the computer having a low battery, for example by `10%`. However, when I turn the computer back on (without having gone through recharging), the computer has about `70%`.

Here is a graphic example. In the yellow-orange colored time slot, the computer was turned off with about 10% battery. It was off for ~1.45h. No interaction of any kind (and of course without having loaded it). The laptop was stored in the backpack until the moment of turning it on again; when the charge was no longer at 10% but between 70% and 60%.

[image: back graph]

I don't have much knowledge as to how the Linux system manages the battery. But I see that this problem could be in how the software interprets the battery and not in a problem with the battery itself (?).

How could I proceed or what actions could I do to check it? is it possible that it does not display the percentage value as it should?

**About voltage:**

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727374/373893):

> The battery's minimum design voltage (= should never be discharged to below this voltage) is 11400000 microvolts = 11.4 volts.

However, I check that constantly, not being connected to AC under this value:

[image: voltage graph]

As you can see, only when it exceeds the threshold is when I have connected the laptop to electric current.

**About amperage**

When it was new, the battery claims to have had a fully-charged capacity of 4.10 amp-hours:

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design
4100000
```

But it has since then degraded so the current fully-charged capacity is only 0.9 amp-hours. Currently, it has 0.675 amp-hours of charge left.

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full
900000
```

However, I don't understand why I usually keep `charge_now` over `charge_full`. I don't see the point in it:

[image: amp graph]

Can this degradation have something to do with the problem? Could it then have something to do with the hardware battery status any problem with voltage or amperage? could the strange behavior then be explained by a hardware problem?

And if so; what is the logic of the problems related to the range of 8 and with that of magically increasing the battery sometimes?