# It is possible to recalibrate power_supply_charge_full in /sys/class/power_supply?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, power-management

I explain myself, recently I have found strange problems related to the battery (`BAT0`) on my laptop, which seems not to be working as it should. More information [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725724/strange-battery-behavior-how-to-diagnose-power-supply-monitor) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726822/373893).

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_TYPE=Battery
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Full
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=11400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12737000
POWER_SUPPLY_CURRENT_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL_DESIGN=4100000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_FULL=24900000
POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_NOW=24900000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=100
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Full
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=standard
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=OEM
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=00001
```

The fact is that from one day to the next, the value of `power_charge_full` (in microampere-hours or Ah) has shot up incomprehensibly. Before it was at the value of 900000 (well below the design one, I know).

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full
900000
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design
4100000
```

This meant that the fully charged capacity was 0.9 Ah, when the battery indicates that it initially had a fully charged capacity of 4.10 Ah. However now the value changed to 24900000.

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full
24900000
```

**This is exorbitant, and would make the total capacity of 24.9Ah. This is patently wrong.**

Here I show a proof of the moment when the data mutated in time:

[image: graph zabbix]

This problem now affects the battery capacity calculations, of course. Now I'm barely under 95% battery, when I should have maybe 40% (for example). And when I finally get to about 85% battery, the computer completely empties and shuts down.

Is there a way to recalibrate this value to get back to at least a more realistic capacity calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I know it is not right, but I only can share my experience.

It is supposed that the only way to re-calibrate is let the battery discharges (to the minimum) and then charge it again to 100%. And after that, let the battery normally working between 40 and 80% all the time.

I had the same problem but not with the same figures as you. I also have `power_charge_full` higher than `power_charge_full_design`, but the difference was lower (I don't remember the exactly figures). It was like I could charge my laptop until 110%, more or less.

As a result, when gnome battery icon showed 100% I got:

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status
Unknown
```

It is supposed that `status` file could say "Unknown", "Charging", "Discharging", "Not charging" or "Full" (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-power). But I got no "Full". On the other hand `capacity` file, which records the percentage, were under 100%. I don't remember exactly, but let suppose 97%. And `capacity` file was stopped on this number, no matter if I let the AC adapter plugged. This percentage matched with `charge_now` / `charge_full`, and both showed the same figure all time.

So I made some test forcing my laptop battery to 100%. When gnome showed 100% and `status` showed "Unknown", I disconnected AC adapter, let de computer decrease percentage a little bit, and plugged AC adapter again. I don't know why but `charge_now` file reached higher value each time and finally I showed 100%. In this moment `status` turned to "Full", and `power_charge_full` change to a new value lesser than `power_charge_full_design`.

Unfortunately, I can not tell you how I exactly did. It was like if "looking" to the files in `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/` (in my case is BAT1) and forcing to 100%, it finally re-calibrated.

I read that reach 100% with the computer on could make the computer loses track of real charging (https://h30467.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-para-notebooks/Consejos-de-mantenimiento-de-Bater%C3%ADas-Ion-Litio-en/td-p/66885). Maybe another try could be let the AC adapter on with the computer off, enough time to completely battery charge, and then switch on the computer and check `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/` files.

I hope it helps.